# SQL Server prepared statement execution - strange behavior

Tags: sql-server, prepared-statement

I have some .NET application which communicates with a SQL Server 2012 database.

Generally it gets a request from the client, runs some set of SQL queries to process the request and returns the result. To optimize performance, I prepare all the queries at startup and then execute the prepared statements each and every time. This works good most of the time, but occasionally I got some strange performance glitches, so I tried to investigate what's going on with the help of profiler.

I caught *Showplan XML Statistics Profile* and *RPC:Completed* events.

When the application behaves normally, I can see in profiler that on startup it executes something like:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1 = 5

exec sp_prepexec @p1 output, N'@my_param_list', N'select my_field from my_table'
```

and then on each client request:

```
exec sp_execute 5, @myparam1=value1, @myparam2=value2 ...
```

Before this *RPC:Completed* line I can see *Showplan XML Statistics Profile*  event with pretty normal execution plan. The duration of the query is ~50ms, which is good.

Now, when the problem occurs, I can see in profiler about 2500(!) lines of *Showplan XML Statistics Profile* events - each one with some meaningless index scan on one of the tables participating in the query (the only difference is the index which participates in the scan), followed by "Stream Aggregate" . And after all these lines I can see at last *RPC:Completed* event with the following text:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1 = NULL 

exec sp_prepexec @p1 output, N'@my_param_list', N'select my_field from my_table'
```

and the duration of more than **30 seconds**. I can't understand why it takes so long, what is the meaning of all these scans, and why the handler is NULL in `sp_prepexec`. It looks to me like SQL Server tries very hard to execute the prepared statement, than abandons it or probably tries to re-prepare it.

So I'd be happy to get an explanation of what's wrong with this and what is going on.... Thanks in advance and sorry for the long explanation.

Comment: I'd guess you are running into a Parameter Sniffing issue. Try append `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN);` to your queries, see if that solves the issue.

Comment: @TT - I thought about Parameter Sniffing, but I don't think it can explain 2500 scans of the same table in one query. Also, I have pretty good estimation of the relevant data - it is distributed evenly.